# Hierarchy in the array РHP

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I have a function that build a Tree Array. Example:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12
            [address] => 'Ukraine'
            [parent_id] => 0
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 11
                            [address] => Crimea
                            [parent_id] => 12
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 16
                                            [address] => Yalta
                                            [parent_id] => 11
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

I have function to print Tree (I want to get output with levels indented):

```
function printTree($data) {
    foreach ($data as $item) {
        if ($item['parent_id'] != 0) 
            echo ' - ' . $item['address'] . "<br>";
        else 
            echo $item['address'] . "<br>";

        if (isset($item['children'])) {
            printTree($item['children']);
        }
    }
}
```

But my result is only with one levels indets, because my `if` is not correct:

```
Ukraine
 - Crimea
 - Yalta
```

I need to get with all levels indents. What do I need to change in my `if` statement?

```
Ukraine
 - Crimea
 - Yalta
```

Comment: Your solution is _iterative_ [you use a `foreach`], you need a _recursive_ one [a function that calls itself]: you have keywords enough to perform a search, good luck : ))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite your code this way:

```
function printTree($data, $level = 0) {
    foreach ($data as $item) {
        if ($item['parent_id'] != 0) {
             /* here we corrects indent: */
             echo str_repeat('&nbsp;', $level) . ' - ' . $item['address'] . "<br>"; 
        } else {
             echo $item['address'] . "<br>";                   
        }

        if (isset($item['children'])) {
               printTree($item['children'], $level + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just add a depth variable to control how many blanks you want add before each child item:

```
<?php
$data = array(
    0 => array(
        'id' => 12,
        'address' => 'Ukraine',
        'parent_id' => 0,
        'children' => array(
            0 => array(
                'id' => 11,
                'address' => Crimea,
                'parent_id' => 12,
                'children' => array(
                    0 => array(
                        'id' => 16,
                        'address' => Yalta,
                        'parent_id' => 11,
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
);

printTree($data);

function printTree($data, $depth = 0) {
    foreach ($data as $item) {

        if ($item['parent_id'] != 0)
            echo str_repeat('&nbsp;', $depth), "- {$item['address']}\n"; 
        else
            echo "{$item['address']}\n";

        if (isset($item['children'])) {
            printTree($item['children'], ++$depth);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Output:

```
Ukraine
 - Crimea
  - Yalta
```

#### [Working demo.](http://codepad.org/DQTwluCB)